# Chrome sometimes incorrectly displaying '⇱' symbol used as css pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a style with pseudo-element:

```
a::before {
  content: "⇱"
}
```

In my html file there is a link:

```
<a href="..."> 1 <a>
```

Most of the time it's displayed correctly:

[image]

But sometimes (not often, maybe 1 time out of 100) Chrome displays it like this:

[image]

It looks like encoding problem, but what could be the reason of it?

Comment: Is this only with links?

Comment: @ARI FISHER I'm not sure, I don't have pseudo-styles for other elements. Kind of hard to test this, because it's hard to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [CSS content code of ⇱](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/north-west-arrow-to-corner/) to avoid encoding issues:

```css
a::before {
  content: '\21F1';
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```